# Odoo: How are product.template records created and linked to product.product records in product module demo data

Tags: odoo, odoo-15

I know how to define demo data using XML files and usage of the corresponding xml ids. However, I am not able to understand how most of the product.template records are defined in the odoo product module demo data.

For example, In Odoo v15.0, I can see the definition of below record in product/data/product_demo.xml

```
❯ grep product_product_27 product/
product/data/product_demo.xml
489:    <record id="product_product_27" model="product.product">
```

However, I am not able to find the definition of product_product_27_product_template (product.template) anywhere, even though it is being referenced in the same file,

```
❯ grep product_product_27_product_template product/
product/data/product_demo.xml
748:    <field name="product_tmpl_id" ref="product_product_27_product_template"/>
```

1. Where is product_product_27_product_template defined (product.template) defined?
2. How is it linked with product_product_27 (product.product)?

Comment: Very interessting question. I don't no the answer, but i guess Odoo generates the external id (xml id) automatically for demo data, in such cases (delegation inheritance)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Odoo loads [product/data/product_demo.xml](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/16.0/addons/product/data/product_demo.xml#L490) file and creates the `Drawer` record (id=`product_product_27`), it will compute the parent record external id based on the following expression:

```py
'xml_id': f"{data['xml_id']}_{parent_model.replace('.', '_')}",
```

*Odoo will  add [XML ids](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/odoo/models.py#L4449) for parent records that have just been created*